# How do I pass a formula to lm() without error?

Tags: r, formula, lm

I try to pass a formula to lm(). However, when I do the following:

```
independend_vars <- c("PC_1_food_men","covar_prev_diab")
dependent_var <- c("PC_1_mets_men", "PC_2_mets_men", "PC_3_mets_men")

var_names <- independend_vars

formula <- as.formula(paste0(dependent_var, "~", paste0(var_names, collapse = "+")))
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning:
Using formula(x) is deprecated when x is a character vector of length > 1.
  Consider formula(paste(x, collapse = " ")) instead.
```

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: Try only `formula()`

Comment: We need an example please as your code should work i.e. try it for `dependent_var = "y" ; var_names = c("x1", "x2")` ps there is also `?reformulate` ... h im guessing you have multiple dependent variables? i.e. `dependent_var = c("y", "z")`

Comment: Check `paste0(dependent_var, "~", paste0(var_names, collapse = "+"))` and see why the warning message says it has length > 1.

Comment: @Duck Unfortunately formula() does not work.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas I have got the right content when checking just paste0(dependent_var, "~", paste0(var_names, collapse = "+")): "PC_1_mets_men~PC_1_food_men+covar_prev_diab" "PC_2_mets_men~PC_1_food_men+covar_prev_diab" "PC_3_mets_men~PC_1_food_men+covar_prev_diab"..... However, the complete syntax wit as.formula() throws a error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a warning (not an error) because in the question `dependent_var` has more than one element and it is letting you know it is ignoring all but the first element.  Also note that you don't have to convert the string to a formula as `lm` will accept a character string but if given a character vector of length > 1 it will ignore all but the first element and give a similar warning.

We can modify the code in the question to this:

```
paste(sprintf("cbind(%s)", toString(dependent_var)), "~", 
  paste(var_names, collapse = " + "))
```

giving:

```
[1] "cbind(PC_1_mets_men, PC_2_mets_men, PC_3_mets_men) ~ PC_1_food_men + covar_prev_diab"
```

however, using `reformulate` as in the next section is a bit easier.

### reformulate

Instead, we can form the LHS using `sprintf` and then use that with the independent variables in `reformulate`.  Using the built in CO2 data set so that we can actually run the result:

```
dep_vars <- names(CO2)[4:5]    # c("conc", "uptake")
indep_vars <- names(CO2)[2:3]  # c("Type", "Treatment")

fo <- reformulate(indep_vars, sprintf("cbind(%s)", toString(dep_vars)))
fo
## cbind(conc, uptake) ~ Type + Treatment

lm(fo, CO2)
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = fo, data = CO2)

Coefficients:
                  conc        uptake    
(Intercept)        4.350e+02   3.697e+01
TypeMississippi   -5.582e-14  -1.266e+01
Treatmentchilled   0.000e+00  -6.860e+00
```

The question had multiple dependent variables but if there were only one then we could simplify the reformulate statement.  For example, to only use the first dependent variable:

```
reformulate(indep_vars, dep_vars[1])
## conc ~ Type + Treatment
```

### Nicer looking Call line

The Call: line above shows the RHS as literally `fo` but we can use `do.call` to force it to produce a nicer looking Call: line.

```
do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(CO2)))
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = cbind(conc, uptake) ~ Type + Treatment, data = CO2)

Coefficients:
                  conc        uptake    
(Intercept)        4.350e+02   3.697e+01
TypeMississippi   -5.582e-14  -1.266e+01
Treatmentchilled   0.000e+00  -6.860e+00
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a vector of dependent variables, so you have a vector of formulas after your `paste` call. You can only pass one at a time to `as.formula`:

```r
independend_vars <- c("PC_1_food_men","covar_prev_diab")
dependent_var <- c("PC_1_mets_men", "PC_2_mets_men", "PC_3_mets_men")

var_names <- independend_vars
string_form <- paste0(dependent_var, "~", paste0(var_names, collapse = "+"))

string_form
#> [1] "PC_1_mets_men~PC_1_food_men+covar_prev_diab"
#> [2] "PC_2_mets_men~PC_1_food_men+covar_prev_diab"
#> [3] "PC_3_mets_men~PC_1_food_men+covar_prev_diab"

as.formula(string_form)
#> Warning: Using formula(x) is deprecated when x is a character vector of length > 1.
#>   Consider formula(paste(x, collapse = " ")) instead.
#> PC_1_mets_men ~ PC_1_food_men + covar_prev_diab
```

If you want 3 different formulas, you can do `as.formula` in an `lapply`

```
lapply(string_form, as.formula)
#> [[1]]
#> PC_1_mets_men ~ PC_1_food_men + covar_prev_diab
#> <environment: 0x0000000015620b28>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> PC_2_mets_men ~ PC_1_food_men + covar_prev_diab
#> <environment: 0x0000000015620b28>
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> PC_3_mets_men ~ PC_1_food_men + covar_prev_diab
#> <environment: 0x0000000015620b28>
```

If you don't want 3 formulas, it's not clear to me what you're trying to do.

<sup>Created on 2020-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>